# Converting google map store locator to laravel is not working

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

am working on google map store locator, to search my stores in particular locations. I got the entire functionality worked correctly with core PHP by referring google map store locator link.
 But actually I want the functionality to get worked in laravel.

I converted it into laravel and am getting errors.

Following is my code, am displaying here only important codes, there are chances for error

```
var searchUrl = '{{ route('gmap') }}?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
```

Here in official documentation, they are providing direct link abc.php instead of that I created a route and provided that

Following is the code in the controller, I directly copy-pasted core PHP code to that controller, am getting an error

```
 public function gmap()
    {
        // Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new \DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id,locationName, locationAddress1, locationLat, locationLong, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( locationLat ) ) * cos( radians( locationLong ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( locationLat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$center_lng),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$radius));
$result =$con->query($query);
//$result = $con->query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());
}
//header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['locationName']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['locationAddress1']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['locationLat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['locationLong']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
    }
```

here `$con` is undefined document error, how can I convert this to laravel. Please help I got stuck into this work for the last 3 weeks. Please help

Answer (score 0):

First you should add the Request by dependency injection, what is automatically [injected by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#method-injection):

```php
public function gmap(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
```

Next, you do not want to use $_GET directly, as this can potentially lead to SQL injections, what would be a security issue. Instead, [get the parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#accessing-the-request) from the `$request`:

```php
$center_lat = $request->input("lat");
$center_lng = $request->input("lng");
$radius = $request->input("radius");
```

The way you generate the XML response can surely be approved, but for now, that should be fine. So, let's keep it as it is.

```php
$dom = new \DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
```

Instead of requesting the data directly from the database, you want to use the built-in [database feature of Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#main-content). Instead of using the DB facade, I would even recommend using models to have the full power of [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent). But that would need extra refinements on other locations in your code, so for now, I will show the way by using the DB facade (`Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`).

Make sure to set up the .env file correctly for your database connection!

```php
$locations = DB::table('locations')
    ->selectRaw("id, locationName, locationAddress1, locationLat, locationLong"
            . ", ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('?') ) * cos( radians( locationLat ) ) * cos( radians( locationLong ) - radians('?') ) + sin( radians('?') ) * sin( radians( locationLat ) ) ) ) AS distance", 
        [$center_lat, $center_lng, $center_lat]
    )
    ->havingRaw("distance < '?'", $radius)
    ->orderByRaw("distance")
    ->limit(20)
    ->get();
```

This will give you an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` what is like a `stdClass` on steroids.

As Laravel does the error handling by itself, you can get rid of the Invalid query error:

```php
//if (!$result) {
//  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());
//}
```

To now set the attributes, you can iterate through the result, for example by `foreach`:

```php
foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("id", $location->id);
    $newnode->setAttribute("name", $location->locationName);
    $newnode->setAttribute("address", $location->locationAddress1);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $location->locationLat);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $location->locationLong);
    $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $location->distance);
}
```

Last, you do not want to echo the output, but instead return the output as a response and then let Laravel do the rest.

```php
    return response($dom->saveXML(), 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

So, in total, your controller function will look like this:

```php
public function gmap(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $center_lat = $request->input("lat");
    $center_lng = $request->input("lng");
    $radius = $request->input("radius");

    $dom = new \DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

    $locations = DB::table('locations')
        ->selectRaw("id, locationName, locationAddress1, locationLat, locationLong"
                . ", ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('?') ) * cos( radians( locationLat ) ) * cos( radians( locationLong ) - radians('?') ) + sin( radians('?') ) * sin( radians( locationLat ) ) ) ) AS distance", 
            [$center_lat, $center_lng, $center_lat]
        )
        ->havingRaw("distance < '?'", $radius)
        ->orderByRaw("distance")
        ->limit(20)
        ->get();

    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
        $newnode->setAttribute("id", $location->id);
        $newnode->setAttribute("name", $location->locationName);
        $newnode->setAttribute("address", $location->locationAddress1);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $location->locationLat);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $location->locationLong);
        $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $location->distance);
    }

    return response($dom->saveXML(), 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```